# R fill up a matrix with conditional statements

Tags: r, matrix, conditional-statements, fill

I have a table which contains the datas about the arrival and leaving time of the employees. The time range is given as time intervals of 30 min:

```
arrival <- c("04:01 - 4:30","00:31 - 1:00","05:01 - 5:30","06:31 - 7:00","08:01 - 8:30") 
leaving <- c("08:31 - 9:00","04:01 - 4:30","06:31 - 7:00","07:31 - 8:00","08:01 - 8:30") 
id <- c("A", "B","C","D","E") 
df <- data.frame(id,arrival,leaving)
```

[image]

I want to know how many people are situated at the working places at the same time.
For this purpose has to be filled up the following matrix:

```
a <- c("00:00 - 00:30", "00:31 - 1:00",  "01:01 - 1:30",  "01:31 - 2:00",
       "02:01 - 2:30",  "02:31 - 3:00",  "03:01 - 3:30",  "03:31 - 4:00",
       "04:01 - 4:30",  "04:31 - 5:00",  "05:01 - 5:30",  "05:31 - 6:00",  
       "06:01 - 6:30",  "06:31 - 7:00",  "07:01 - 7:30",  "07:31 - 8:00", 
       "08:01 - 8:30",  "08:31 - 9:00") 
b <- c("A", "B","C","D","E") 
mat <- matrix("", ncol = length(a),nrow=length(b)) 
colnames(mat) <- c(a) 
rownames(mat) <- c(b)
```

[image]

As a result, I need this matrix to be filled up in the following way:

[image]

For this purpose, it have to be checked the conditions:

```
If(colnames(mat)>=df$arrival)&(colnames(mat)<=leaving){1}else if(df$arrival = df$leaving){1} else (0)
```

Put in other words it has to be checked if the arrival time equal or later to the time in columns of the matrix, and the time of leaving is equal or earlier to the time in columns of the matrix. If the conditions are filled up, it has to be put „1” during this period. If arrival time is equal to leaving time, it has to be put "1" only once. Other cells must contain "0"

Thank You in advance for Your answers!

Comment: I occasionally think about this post and how someone copied-pasted my answer and made it worse (by removing clarity with messy code). Because the community has upvoted my answer more, do you think you could mark it as the accepted one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mat<-matrix(0, ncol = length(a),nrow=length(b)) 
colnames(mat)<-a 
rownames(mat)<-b

#Then we find the column that matches the arrival and the one that matches the leaving    

for(i in 1:length(id)) mat[i,which(a==arrival[i]):which(a==leaving[i])]=1
```

Answer (score 4):

First off, you'll want to initialize your matrix with 0s instead of ""s, as you want them to be 0 by default, yes?

```
# initialize your matrix with 0s instead of ""
mat <- matrix( 0, ncol = length(a), nrow=length(b))
colnames(mat) <- c(a) 
rownames(mat) <- c(b)
```

Although I'm loathe to use a for-loop, this may be an appropriate case. Using lapply() returns a list of 1s.

```
# mark them on the timesheet
for( i in 1:length(id) ) {
  arrive <- which(colnames(mat) == arrival[i])
  leave <- which(colnames(mat) == leaving[i])
  mat[id[i], arrive : leave] <- 1
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, You are right. I should create a matrix with "0".
It works! Thank You very much!